# Problem to load plugin GitHubNotebookRepo and GCSNotebookRepo on Zeppelin using Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-zeppelin, google-cloud-dataproc

I tried to save my notebooks on GCS and GitHub without success.

I have the error below:

```
INFO [2020-07-23 19:54:59,790] ({qtp684874119-16} PluginManager.java[loadNotebookRepo]:60) - Loading NotebookRepo Plugin: org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GCSNotebookRepo
WARN [2020-07-23 19:54:59,791] ({qtp684874119-16} PluginManager.java[loadNotebookRepo]:68) - Fail to instantiate notebookrepo from classpath directly:org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GCSNotebookRepo
WARN [2020-07-23 19:54:59,791] ({qtp684874119-16} PluginManager.java[getPluginClassLoader]:181) - PluginFolder /usr/lib/zeppelin/plugins/NotebookRepo/GCSNotebookRepo doesn't exist or is not a directory
```

Anyone can help me please?

thanks!

Comment: May you provide a command that you use to create a Dataproc cluster and command which you use to install these Zepplin plugins?

Comment: I tried to found this flag to install this plugins without success.

Comment: What Dataproc image version do you use?

Comment: I tried debian and ubuntu 1.5 and preview.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Zeppelin installation on Dataproc 1.5 and 2.0 preview images is missing GCS plugin, you can either download it from [Maven Central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/zeppelin/notebookrepo-gcs/0.9.0-preview1/) or use Dataproc 1.4 that has `GCSNotebookRepo` plugin pre-installed.

In upcoming releases we will bundle `GCSNotebookRepo` plugin in Dataproc 1.5 and 2.0 preview by default too.

Comment: Thanks! Please and Github plugin too.

Comment: New Dataproc 1.5 and 2.0 preview images with bundle Zeppelin plugins will be released  by next EOW, August 7.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Igor, did the new 1.5 with github and gcs plugins were released?

Comment: Release is rolling out now, should be rolled out globally by this Friday.